# R - Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : err in arg 'x' in selecting a mthd for fun 'as.matrix': not-yet-implemented mthd 4 <df> %*% <dgMatrix>

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression, forecasting

This one is a real headscratcher.
All of the code included in this question and the datasets loaded into my script can be found in my [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/Spencermstarr/Forecasting-US-Stock-Prices) for this applied predictive analytics (using R) project.

First thing is first, the actual full error message I got in the console without any abbreviations was the following:

```
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as.matrix': not-yet-implemented method for <data.frame> %*% <dgCMatrix>
```

I have a 225 by 3808 dataframe called data2014 where I have already deliberately removed all non-numeric columns and interpolated all NAs in it initially. This error appears multiple times for me as I attempt to run/train a Ridge Regression on my stock data from 2014.
The first time it appears is when running the following lines of code:

```
library(Matrix)
library(glmnet)
#grid1 <- 
ridge1.mod = glmnet(x = data2014, y = pr_var2014, alpha = 0,
                    standardize = TRUE)
dim(coef(ridge1.mod))
ridge1.mod
summary(ridge1.mod)
ridge1.pred = predict(ridge1.mod, newx = data2015)
> ridge1.pred = predict(ridge1.mod, newx = data2015)
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as.matrix': not-yet-implemented method for <data. Frame> %*% <dgCMatrix>
```

Note: I previously removed the column in data_2014 which had observed values for the percentage variation in the price of that stock the following year after assigning it to the object pr_var2014 (I misnamed it, it should be called pr_var2015) to avoid any potential multicollinearity issues when predicting that variable/column.
And the second time the identical error message appears in the Console is after running the two following lines of code directly below that, namely:

```
set.seed(11)
cv.out1 = cv.glmnet(data2014, pr_var2014, alpha = 0)
> cv.out1 = cv.glmnet(data2014, pr_var2014, alpha = 0)
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as.matrix': not-yet-implemented method for <data.frame> %*% <dgCMatrix>
```

These erros are especially perxlexing to me because I am going directly off of the directions for how to run a Ridge Regression in the well known and well respected textbook "An Introduction to Statistical Learning *with Applications in R*", so I don't understand what could be the problem here.